# SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, hosting, cpanel

I built a simple website for my mother's business. There is no login, database, or any sort of form or payment happening on the site. I do not have an SSL Certificate and was wondering if a self-signed one offered by cPanel hosting would suffice? I would hate to shell out money for encryption I don't need yet. The main reason I need it is so that the browsers stop blocking my https connection. Any information I can get on this would be a big help.

Comment: Look at startssl.com or letsencrypt

Comment: Thanks so I have been looking into that. I have no idea where to start. It seems very complicated with needing to install through shell access? I started to setup the ssh access on cPanel then had to get PuTTy and now I am lost. Not sure how to connect to the server through puTTy. Is there an easier way I haven't found?

Comment: This question is not about programming and is off-topic is SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than selecting a self-signed SSL Certificate, you better go with the Free/Trial SSL Certificate offered by some of world's leading SSL Certificate authorities like Comodo, Symantec and RapidSSL.

**Why no to Self-Signed SSL Certificate?**

- Not accepted by most browsers
- Browser will display untrusted connection error message

**Why Free/Trial SSL Certificate?**

- Compatible with multiple servers and operating system platforms.
- Accepted by 99.9% web and mobile browsers (No Error after installation)
- It will give trust and confidence to users as the SSL is from verified SSL authority
- Increases website reputation over internet.